# How does GridSearchCV works?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I'm studying neural networks, I have to tune some hyperpar with gridsearchCV, the part related to the code is clear, but I don't understand how gridsearch works.
Can you explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call out parameter $\theta$. Grid search CV works by first specifying a grid, $\Theta$ of thetas to search over. For each $\theta \in \Theta$, we perform Kfold CV with the paramter of our model set to $\theta$.  This gives a cv loss value for each $\theta$ and so we can pick the $\theta$ which minimizes cv loss.

Comment: Ok thanks. I noticed that if I don't write the number of epochs it works correctly without problem. In this case how many epochs are used?